# Decoding from array json

Tags: json, url, decode

how can i decode values from JSON array on certain URL?

```
array(8) 
{
 ["name"]=> string(18) "Server for testing"
 ["map"]=> string(12) "pointlessMap"
 ["game"]=> string(4) "game"
 ["description"]=> string(12) "No desc. set"
 ["players"]=> int(5)
 ["playersmax"]=> int(100)
 ["password"]=> int(0
 ["vac"]=> int(1)
}
```

i tried to decode players:

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('http://url here/index.php');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->array[5]->players;

?>
```

I need to decode "players", thanks for any helping.

Comment: Whats the output from the `echo`?

Comment: it's empty.....

Comment: Try this instead of the `echo` statement `print_r($obj);` then what does it say?